# How to use CSS clases with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am building a site with Next.js and Tailwind and wanted to know if there is any way you can use Tailwind CSS classes along with Next.js classes. For example:

```
<img src={user.picture} className="rounded"{styles.pfp}></img>
```

or perhaps something like

```
<img src={user.picture} className=`rounded{styles.pfp}`></img>
```

Is there any way to do that? Do let me know if there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the way to do it would be like this:

```
<img src={user.picture} className={`rounded ${styles.pfp}`}></img>
```

with `rounded` being the Tailwind class and `styles.pfp` being your class.

Comment: Unless the `styles.pfp` variables are defined before tailwind builds its classes, it won't work. For that kind of scenario, [safelisting](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) should be used.